# Ubuntu OpenCV error while reading webCamera

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, ubuntu, webcam

I can run the same program in Windows. I can see my camera using lsusb in Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bits. The camera is an OSVR infrared camera.

My program is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('camera', frame)

    #    k = cv2.waitKey(30)

# When everything done, release the capture
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The results are:

```
cwu@ubuntu:~/project/osvrCamera$ python test.py 
select timeout
select timeout
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!buf.empty() && buf.isContinuous()) in imdecode_, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp, line 490
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
ret, frame = camera.read() 
cv2.error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:490: error: (-215) !buf.empty() && buf.isContinuous() in function imdecode_
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the frame isn't `empty()` first (maybe cam/frame isn't fully initialised when you try to convert/display it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    if not frame.empty():
       cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

       cv2.imshow('camera', frame)

    #    k = cv2.waitKey(30)

# When everything done, release the capture
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```